# Only the last record from the database is displayed

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I connected, I created a quick script in which I want to manage clients, domains and notes.

The problem is that when I add 2 notes to the client from ID: 1 - after viewing I see only one.

The following code shows what I have done so far

SQL Query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM domain JOIN note ON domain.id = note.domain_id GROUP BY domain.id";
```

My PHP code:

```
while($rs = $resultdb->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$rs["id"].'</td>';
    echo '<td><strong><a href="'.$rs["domain_name"].'" target="_blank">'.$rs["domain_name"].'</a></strong></td>';
    echo '<td>'.$rs["note"].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
```

The result he gets is:

```
ID   DOMAIN    NOTE

1    "domain1.com"  "note 1 to domain1.com"

2    "domain2.com"  "note 2 to domain2.com"
```

However, in the database I have added a few notes to domain1.com.

I would like to see all the notes added to a given domain.

EDIT:

When I do: `"SELECT * FROM domain JOIN note ON domain.id = note.domain_id";`

I getting:

[I getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANIin.png)

[I expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHjbK.png)

EDIT: Add screnshot

[LEFT JOIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tOlN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GROUP BY is limiting the records retrieved by the query.  If you want all of the notes together you can try using [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to produce a single field with all of the notes in one...

```
$sql = "SELECT domain.id as id, domain.domain_name as domain_name,
             GROUP_CONCAT(note.note) as note 
           FROM domain 
           LEFT JOIN note ON domain.id = note.domain_id 
           GROUP BY domain.id";
```

You might also change the JOIN to LEFT JOIN in case there are no notes for a particular domain.

Comment: However, no, all data is missing, e.g. domain ID - where I do not have a note added.

Can I get around this?

Comment: Yes LEFT JOIN is helpful, it shows all the records, however, it does not show, for example, the domain ID there where there is no note.

Comment: Can you show the SQL that you have used for this as well.

Answer (score 0):

you need  group_concat group  by  note.domain_id

if you need  exact match the use inner join

```
 "SELECT  id, domain, group_concat(note) as note 
    FROM domain 
    INNER JOIN note ON domain.id = note.domain_id
    GROUP BY note.domain_id";
```

if you needc result also for id without notes  then try

```
 "SELECT  id, domain, (group_concat(ifnull(note,'')) as note 
    FROM domain 
    LEFT JOIN note ON domain.id = note.domain_id
    GROUP BY note.domain_id";
```

Comment: However, no, all data is missing, e.g. domain ID - where I do not have a note added.

Can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to use a separate query to get "Domain Notes" in the while. for example:

```
while ($rs = $resultdb->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $sql_notes = "SELECT * FROM notes WHERE domain_id = '" . (int)$rs['domain_id'] . "'";

    ...
}
```